# remove even number of duplicate entries in excel

Tags: excel

I have a data in excel where there are multiple duplicate cells . In excel i want to remove all duplicate entries(remove complete row) occurring even number of times. There can be repetition any number of times i.e 2,3,4,5.... Also, i wanted to keep only one copy of entries occurring odd number of times. How can i do this?

Ex.
say i have these records as key cell in my excel sheet

```
58795
67835
68545
68545
68555
68555
68625
68625
68625
```

My expected output is

```
58795
67835
68625
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Take a look at [**how to ask a good question**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can use `COUNTIF` and `ISODD` functions to set up a filter. Like so:

[image]
[image]

Then filter the `IsOdd = TRUE`, copy them somewhere and use Data > Remove Duplicates feature of excel to keep only one copy of the odd ones.